# Can you add some CSS to a dropdown that isn't selected?

Tags: jquery

Say I wanted to change the text color to red for a dropdown that hasn't been chosen/clicked/interacted with. What would be the best approach?

I've tried this in the class of my dropdown:

```
             <?php (if $myVar = 0) { echo "highlight-dropdown"; } ?>
```

`$myVar` is a database stored variable, 0 = not selected.

Comment: What difference does it make whether or not its selected?

Comment: $myVar = 0 will set the variable to zero. Use "==" or "===" for comparison!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a css class for it and than removeClass if you do something with it. This way you can easily change the style via css.